# How can I allow edit ranges in a protected worksheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, worksheet

I wanna block only some ranges. In other words, I wanna allow editing in a protected worksheet. I'm able to do this manually, and even recording a macro while doing it. But when I try to run the code of this process, the error window pops up on my screen.

Code:

```
ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Intervalo3", Range:= _
        Range("H18")
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

Errors:
Runtime error 1004
Application definition or object definition error.

I tried to record a macro of allowing edit ranges in a protected worksheet 'cause I wanted do it automatically. I was successfull in recording the macro allowing editing ranges and protecting the worksheet. But when I went to VBA workspace to try to run the code behind this action, I just wasn't able and the error window popped up.

Comment: Why don't you simply unlock the cells you want the user to edit and then protect the worksheet?

Comment: It works fine when I try your code once. If you run it a second time, manually or through VBA, you must first unlock the worksheet, otherwise you will get this error.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I was having problems trying to pinpoint the error and how to correct that problem. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I've never really played with `AllowEditRanges` - usually I do as @jkpieterse suggests and unlock the cells in the *Format Cells > Protection* dialog before protecting the sheet.  Much easier.

Having said that, it looks like you can't call an `AllowEditRange` object the same name as an existing one which is what your code does if you run it a second time.
You also can't delete the `AllowEditRange` named range if the sheet is protected.

Having said that, this seems to do the trick:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim EditRangeTitle As String
    EditRangeTitle = "Intervalo3"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        .Unprotect
    
        Dim AER As AllowEditRange
        For Each AER In .Protection.AllowEditRanges
            If AER.Title = EditRangeTitle Then Exit For
        Next AER
        
        If Not AER Is Nothing Then
            AER.Delete
        End If
        
        .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:=EditRangeTitle, Range:=.Range("H18")
        .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

This will work on `Sheet1` of the workbook containing the code (`ThisWorkbook`).

Further reading:
[With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)
[ThisWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook)
[For Each...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and helped me a lot. I was having a headache with it haha.